# computing a limit of integrals, maybe using the Convergence dominated theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Let's consider a measure space $(X,M,\mu)$ and $f$ a measurable function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ such that $\int f d\mu <\infty$ , for every $\alpha>0$ compute the following limit:

$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \int {n\log \left( {1 + \left( {\frac{f}
{n}} \right)^\alpha  } \right)d\mu } 
$$

Maybe I have to use the Convergence dominated theorem, but I don't know how.
Maybe $f$ is nonnegative.